# url in codeigniter sometimes show the index.php file, sometimes not

Tags: codeigniter, url

Why does my url show the index.php on startpage but not in links?
I tried to rewrite htaccess but failed. 
I really think it is something easy i am missing.

Comment: put your code in the question

Comment: Open `system/application/config/config.php` and check that `$config['index_page']` is equal to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

use pefect .htaccess for rewriting url:

in config.php change

```
$config['index_page']='';
```

then use the .htaccess in root folder as:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

This work fine for me on server....